# Redux connection working but the function triggered not working

Tags: javascript, react-redux

I'm creating a react web app that sorts the books. I created a redux file, which i'll later connect to the app. But i'm having trouble with the sort logic.

I've created a store with a reducer for the user insert the books and another one to control which kind of sort to perform. I've tested and the sorting state is being change with the store.dispatch. But I couldn't solve why the books are not being sorted with passed criteria. I'm not quite sure if it's a logic problem in my getSortedBooks function.

```
//ACTIONS

//ADD BOOK

const addBook = ({ title = '', author = '', editionYear = 0} = {}) => ({
   type: 'ADD_BOOK',
    book: {
        title,
        author,
        editionYear
    }
});

//SORT BY

const sortBy = (order) => ({
    type: 'SORT_BY',
    orderBy: order

});

//book reducer

const bookReducerDefaultState = [];
const bookReducer = (state = bookReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'ADD_BOOK': 
            return [
                ...state,
                action.book
            ];
        default:    
            return state;
    };
};

//sorting reducer

const sortingReducerDefaultState = { 
    orderBy: ''
};
const sortingReducer = (state = sortingReducerDefaultState, action) => {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'SORT_BY':
            return {
                ...state,
                orderBy: action.orderBy
            };
        case 'SORT_BY_TITLE':
            return {
                ...state,
                sortBy: 'title',
                order: action.order
            };
        case 'SORT_BY_AUTHOR':
            return {
                ...state,
                sortBy: 'author',
                order: action.order
            }
        case 'SORT_BY_EDITION_YEAR':
            return {
                ...state,
                sortBy: 'editionYear',
                order: action.order
            }
        default: 
            return state;
    };   
}


//get sorted books

function getSortedBooks(books, orderBy) {
    orderBy = Array.isArray(orderBy) ? orderBy : [orderBy];
    return books.sort((a, b) => {
        for (let i = 0, size = orderBy.length; i < size; i++) {
            const key = Object.keys(orderBy[i])[0],
                  o = orderBy[i][key],
                  valueA = a[key],
                  valueB = b[key];
                if(!(valueA || valueB)) {
                    console.error("the objects from the data passed does not have the key '" + key + "' passed on sort!");
                    return []; 
                }
                if (+valueA === +valueA) {
                    return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? valueB - valueA : valueA - valueB;
                } else {
                    if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) > 0) {
                        return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
                    } else if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) < 0) {
                        return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? 1 : -1;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    };


//store creation 

const store = createStore(
    combineReducers({
        books: bookReducer,
        sorting: sortingReducer
    })
);

store.subscribe(() => {
    const state = store.getState();
    const sortedBooks = getSortedBooks(state.books, state.sorting.orderBy);
    console.log(sortedBooks);
    // console.log(state);
});

//input data
store.dispatch(addBook({title: 'Java How To Program', author: 'Deitel & Deitel' , editionYear: 2007 }));
store.dispatch(addBook({title: 'Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture ', author: 'Martin Fowler' , editionYear: 2002 }));
store.dispatch(addBook({title: 'Head First Design Patterns  ', author: 'Elisabeth Freeman' , editionYear: 2004 }));
store.dispatch(addBook({title: 'Internet & World Wide Web: How to Program', author: 'Deitel & Deitel' , editionYear: 2007 }));

store.dispatch(sortBy([{editionYear: 'asc'}, {title: 'desc'}]));
```

I expected the result of this sort to be:

```
0: {title: "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture ", author: "Martin Fowler", editionYear: 2002}
1: {title: "Head First Design Patterns  ", author: "Elisabeth Freeman", editionYear: 2004}
2: {title: "Internet & World Wide Web: How to Program", author: "Deitel & Deitel", editionYear: 2007} 
3: {title: "Java How To Program", author: "Deitel & Deitel", editionYear: 2007}
```

but instead it's returning:

```
0: {title: "Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture ", author: "Martin Fowler", editionYear: 2002}
1: {title: "Head First Design Patterns  ", author: "Elisabeth Freeman", editionYear: 2004}
2: {title: "Java How To Program", author: "Deitel & Deitel", editionYear: 2007}
3: {title: "Internet & World Wide Web: How to Program", author: "Deitel & Deitel", editionYear: 2007}
```

as if the function is ignoring the title: desc attribute

Answer (score 0):

In `getSortedBooks`, you never process the second `sortBy` value. In every situation you `return` from the `for` loop in the first iteration.

I've refactored your code and added a working example:

```js
const books = [{
    title: 'Java How To Program',
    author: 'Deitel & Deitel',
    editionYear: 2007
  },
  {
    title: 'Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture ',
    author: 'Martin Fowler',
    editionYear: 2002
  },
  {
    title: 'Head First Design Patterns  ',
    author: 'Elisabeth Freeman',
    editionYear: 2004
  },
  {
    title: 'Internet & World Wide Web: How to Program',
    author: 'Deitel & Deitel',
    editionYear: 2007
  }
]

function compareBy(a, b, orderBy) {
  const key = Object.keys(orderBy)[0],
    o = orderBy[key],
    valueA = a[key],
    valueB = b[key];
  if (!(valueA || valueB)) {
    console.error("the objects from the data passed does not have the key '" + key + "' passed on sort!");
    return 0;
  }
  if (+valueA === +valueA) {
    return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? valueB - valueA : valueA - valueB;
  } else {
    if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) > 0) {
      return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? -1 : 1;
    } else if (valueA.localeCompare(valueB) < 0) {
      return o.toLowerCase() === 'desc' ? 1 : -1;
    }
  }
  return 0
}

function getSortedBooks(books, orderBy) {
  orderBy = Array.isArray(orderBy) ? orderBy : [orderBy];
  return books.sort((a, b) => {
    let result
    for (let i = 0; i < orderBy.length; i++) {
      result = compareBy(a, b, orderBy[i])
      if (result !== 0) {
        return result
      }

    }
    return result
  })
}



console.log('title [asc]:', getSortedBooks(books, [{
  title: 'asc'
}]))
console.log('author [asc]:', getSortedBooks(books, [{
  author: 'asc'
}]))
console.log('editionYear [desc] author [desc] title [asc]:', getSortedBooks(books, [{
  editionYear: 'desc'
}, {
  author: 'desc'
}, {
  title: 'asc'
}]))
console.log('editionYear [desc] author [desc] title [desc]:', getSortedBooks(books, [{
  editionYear: 'desc'
}, {
  author: 'desc'
}, {
  title: 'desc'
}]))
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. Although when I type:

store.dispatch(sortBy([{editionYear: 'desc'}, {author: 'desc'}, {title: 'asc'}]));

it ignores the title condition... why is this happening?

Comment: glad to have helped